# Como pegar o atual usuário no model Django?

Tags: python, django

Olá,

Estou criando uma aplicação em django e tenho um model com a classe NewDemand no qual eu preciso que quando o usuário crie uma demanda, seja salvo em um campo o nome do cara.
Aqui minha classe:

```
class NewDemand(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    date_max = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    requester_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    demand_desc = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Tentei colocar um `models.ForeugnKey(User)` mas na página do admin aparece um campo com um menu que contém todos os usuários. Quero que o nome do usuário vá direto para o banco sem ter que aparece na página admin na hora de inputar os dados.

Comment: a maneira que você vai fazer isso funcionar da maneira que quer, depende de alguns pontos, entre eles: você vai estar utilizando o admin para essa operação de criação de nova demanda? Se sim, você vai ter que usar a lógica que o Marcelo Lino falou na resposta abaixo, junto com algumas modificações no admin. Daí você pode dar uma olhada na [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/) pra ver qual método sobrescrever que melhor vai atender seu problema

Comment: Essa nova Demanda vai poder ser criada por qualquer usuário, basta a pessoa estar apenas logada. Estou usando o esquema de Class-Based View, então estou salvando os dados no método form_valid da minha classe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você aplica essa lógica na view:

```
def new_demand(request):
    user = request.user.id
    demand = NewDemand(name, date_created, date_max, user, demand_desc)
```

Assim você pega o ID do usuário logado e passa como parâmetro pra sua demanda.